# CSS grid of squares with dynamic height?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Full example here: https://codepen.io/ScottBeeson/pen/BmxLxL

```js
$('#btnAddBox').on('click', function() {
  $('.wrapper').append('<div class="box"></div>');
})
$('#btnReset').on('click', function() {
  $('.wrapper').html('<div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>');
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 23px;
  grid-auto-rows: 23px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 23px);
  grid-gap: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 100%;
}

#btnAddBox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 105px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px;
}

#btnReset {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 105px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<div id='btnAddBox'>+ Add Box</div>
<div id='btnReset'>Reset</div>
```

I'm using CSS Grid for a dashboard.  It will be possible to add and remove tiles.  Right now I'm using the following to create a grid of squares:

```
grid-template-rows: repeat(30, 23px);
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 23px);
```

This works, but if I add or remove tiles the height of the wrapper does not adjust accordingly.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grid-auto-rows`. This will not require you to specify the number of rows beforehand like `grid-template-rows`. That makes it auto adjust as the size keeps increasing.

Since your columns are fixed you can use `grid-template-columns` with `repeat(4)`. If you wanted to increase columns then you can achieve it in a similar way using `grid-auto-columns`.

```
.wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; width: 100px;
  display: grid;

  /* Added these */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 23px);
  grid-auto-rows: 23px;
  /* Added these */      

  grid-gap: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```js
$('#btnAddBox').on('click',function() {
  $('.wrapper').append('<div class="box"></div>');
})
$('#btnReset').on('click',function() {
  $('.wrapper').html('<div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div><div class="box"></div>');
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; width: 100px;
  display: grid;
  
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 23px);
  grid-auto-rows: 23px;
  grid-gap: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 100%;
}

#btnAddBox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px; left: 105px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px;
}
#btnReset {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px; left: 105px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<div id='btnAddBox'>+ Add Box</div>
<div id='btnReset'>Reset</div>
```